# List names of files in current directory that don't have numbers inside their body

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having trouble with this exercise. So far I got this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.txt
do
  if grep -qv '[0-9]' $file; then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

Unfortunately with no success. It lists all of my .txt files. As in the Title, I want to check the insides of all files in the directory, and echo the namefile if they contain no numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-v` causes it to match any line that does not contain a digit. If a file contains even one such line, the file will match.

Instead of inverting the match with `-v`, use `!`:

```
for file in *.txt
do
  if ! grep -q '[0-9]' "$file"; then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

You could also do the whole thing with a single `grep` invocation and skip the loop. `-L` prints files that don't match the pattern.

```
grep -L '[0-9]' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for nextfile and ENDFILE:

```
awk '
    /[0-9]/ { f=1; nextfile }
    ENDFILE { if (!f) print FILENAME; f=0 }
' *.txt
```

With any awk:

```
awk '
    /[0-9]/ { f[FILENAME] }
    END { for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) if ( !(ARGV[i] in f) ) print ARGV[i] }
' *.txt
```

The second script has to be written that way to correctly handle empty files.